# How can I preserve the file date time when I switch between branches in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I preserve the file date time when I switch between branches in Visual Studio?

Say I have a Git repo with a number of files, a dev branch and a new feature branch, and I've made an amendment to a single file.

When I switch back and forth between the dev and feature branches, the date/time of the amended file creeps forward ... but the dev version has not been changed!

How can I stop this? ... *old school SCM, so I'm expecting the dev version to revert to the original check-in date/time*

*... the real pain I'm trying to stop is, I want to have a peace of mind backup of dev to an external drive, and I keep seeing file changes, which actually aren't changes ...*

Comment: Why not just backup the repo in a cloud based git host like vsts, GitHub, bitbucket, etcs

Answer (score 1):

First, don't do it. Changing timestamps backward is a problem for tools that rely on timestamps such as `make`.

Second, if switching between branches is a problem — use separate clones. One clone per branch, they are called "worktrees". Git has grown [git worktree](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-worktree.html) command not so long ago, but even if you use older git you can simply manually clone repositories (2 in your case), checkout the proper branches (master and dev) and never change branches again. Of course you need to update them manually — fetch from master repo to dev or vice versa.

Third, there is a [Perl script](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ExampleScripts#Setting_the_timestamps_of_the_files_to_the_commit_timestamp_of_the_commit_which_last_touched_them) that sets the timestamps of the files to the commit timestamp of the commit which last touched them. The script didn't work for me (perhaps completely outdated) so I [rewrote it in Python](http://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=blob;f=set-commit-date.py;hb=HEAD) and use it in those rare situation when I think it's ok to change timestamp backward. You can even use it in post-checkout hook though I recommend against it.

Comment: Yeap, wanted to follow first suggestion, but struggling, however the worktrees sounds just the trick ... if it works in Visual Studio 2017 ?

Comment: No idea, I'm a unixhead. Well, worktrees without any special commands work everywhere where there is git.